# WordPress is_active widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, zurb-foundation

So I have 4 widgets which is in large-3 columns, when they're not active I place a placeholder as user guide so the user would know where to put what.

I did manage to work out the is_active but it turns out to be a long code, I was wondering if there is a way to shorten it.

Widgets from available-course-list-1 to -4

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'available-course-list-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
     <div class="panel">
       <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'available-course-list-1' ); ?></div>
     </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
    <div class="panel">
    <h5>Available Course List #2</h5>
    <p>To add lists courses in this widget, please use the Available Course List widget panel.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'available-course-list-1', 'available-course-list-2' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
         <div class="panel">
           <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'available-course-list-1', 'available-course-list-2' ); ?></div>
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'available-course-list-1' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'available-course-list-2' )) : ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'available-course-list-'.$i ) ) : ?>
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
     <div class="panel">
       <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'available-course-list-'.$i ); ?></div>
     </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
    <div class="panel">
    <h5>Available Course List #2</h5>
    <p>To add lists courses in this widget, please use the Available Course List widget panel.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; 
}
?>
```

Would something like that work?

Comment: I have a feeling that this for loop should be inside <?php ?>, right?